# NodeJS: Download torrent as stream

Tags: node.js, p2p, bittorrent, webtorrent

TL;DR Is is possible to proxy torrent larger than available local disk while piping it to outbound stream ?

According to BitTorrent spec , all torrents are stored as pieces of equal length , I want to write a node app could pipe the torrent pieces to a http upload stream , does any library provide such functionality ?
All the implementation I have found downloads the whole file to local storage then propagate it further which can cause problems when running on small disk and large files .

Comment: What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/torrent-stream ?

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion , will do some testing with the package. But the package dependencies seems to be outdated

Comment: Just first suitable package by a search word "torrent" ). Try to find more up-to-date package

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with webtorrent package as it seems similar

Comment: After my hacky adventure to use webtorrent to get torrent file as stream then pass it to any write Stream . It turns out webtorrent needs to store full file in /tmp storage and thus impossible to stream complete file bigger than local disk . Open for any suggestions

Comment: The prblem with any torrent is it can dowanload parts in a random order so you cannot simply turn it into a stream in any case. If a torrent package can download from the beginning sequentially then it's will be suitable for streaming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bittorrent is designed for random access to keep data available via the rarest-first strategy. See [Section 2.4.2 of the bittorrent econ paper](https://www.bittorrent.org/bittorrentecon.pdf). While it is possible to operate it in a streaming manner anyway this generally isn't recommended and certainly shouldn't be the default, otherwise performance could severely degrade for all swarm members or content could even become unavailable.

Comment: I do understand seeding is core part of a p2p network but as my problem being local storage on server , I was hoping to use seperate storage backend to seed the completed torrent.

Comment: If you have separate storage somewhere else maybe a network filesystem would solve you problem? or do you mean libtorrent's storage backends?